# What παρακαλεῖτε precisely means ? Heb 3:13

Tags: greek

What that greek word (strong: 3870) means precisely ? to encourage or to teach or to counsel or to look after someone or to say thanks or others things ?
I absolutely need it to do Heb 3:13.

Answer (score 1):

**What παρακαλεῖτε precisely means ? Heb 3:13**

**Παρακαλεῖτε means to continuously encourage/exhort**

Paul warns the Hebrews of the peril of an unbelieving heart, the expression  "take  care" emphasizes the need to be watchful,attentive, lack of faith may lead to sin in our heart and could draw us away  from God.

Then Paul reminds Christians to continuously "παρακαλεῖτε" = encourage/exhort one another in the congregation, so that no one takes backward steps by being hardened by the deceptive power of sin.

Hebrews 3:12-13  (NASB)

> 12 "Take care, brethren, that there not be in any one of you an evil,
>   unbelieving heart that falls away from the living God. 13 But
>   **encourage** one another day after day, as long as it is still called
>   “Today,” so that none of you will be hardened by the deceitfulness of
>   sin."

Hebrews 3:12-13  (NRSV)

> 12 "Take care, brothers and sisters, that none of you may have an
>   evil, unbelieving heart that turns away from the living God. 13 But
>   **exhort** one another every day, as long as it is called “today,” so that none of you may be hardened by the deceitfulness of sin."

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word Heb 3:13 is παρακαλέω (parakaleó), from para and kaleo; to call near, i.e. Invite, invoke..  It occurs 109 times in the GNT.  According to BDAG it has the following meanings:

1. **to ask to come and be present where the speaker is, *call to one's side***; eg, Acts 28:20, Luke 8:41, 15:28, etc.
2. **to urge strongly, *appeal to, urge, exhort, encourage***; eg, Acts 16:40, 2 Cor 10:1, 1 Thess 2:12, 5:11, Heb 3:13, Acts 20:1, 2, 1 Tim 5;1, 1 Cor 4:16, 14:31, etc.
3. **to make a strong request for something, *request, implore***; eg, Matt 8:5, 18:32, Mark 1:40, 2 Cor 12:18, etc.
4. **to instill someone with courage or cheer, *comfort, encourage, cheer up***; eg, 2 Cor 1:4b, 7:6a, 2 Cor 7:6b, etc.
5. **treat someone in an inviting or congenial manner, *invite in, conciliate, be friendly to, speak to in a friendly manner***; eg, Luke 15:28, Acts 16:39, etc.

In Heb 3:13, we have (according to BDAG's list) meaning #2 above.  As such the various versions have rendered it: "But encourage one another daily" (NIV), "But exhort one another every day" (ESV), "But exhort one another daily" (BSB), "But encourage one another day after day" (NASB), "Instead, continue to encourage one another every day" (ISV), etc.

The Pulpit commentary observes:

> Verse 13. - But exhort one another (literally, yourselves, as in
>   Colossians 3:16, the idea being that of the responsibility of the
>   believers themselves in keeping their own faith alive; the Church must
>   keep itself from apostasy by the mutual admonitions of its members)

Barnes also notes the following:

> But exhort one another daily - This is addressed to the members of the
>   churches; and it follows, therefore:
>
> (1) that it is their duty to exhort their brethren; and,
>
> (2) that it is their duty to do it "daily;" that is, constantly; see
>   Hebrews 10:25; 1 Thessalonians 4:18; 1 Thessalonians 5:11; note,
>   Romans 12:8. While this is the special duty of the ministers of the
>   gospel 1 Timothy 6:2; 2 Timothy 4:2; Titus 2:6, Titus 2:15, it is also
>   the duty of all the members of the churches, and a most important, but
>   much-neglected duty. This does not refer to "public" exhortation,
>   which more appropriately pertains to the ministers of the gospel, but
>   to that private watch and care which the individual members of the
>   church should have over one another.